# Open Visual Studio 2012 ASP.Net project in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I have created my asp.net project in visual studio 2012, and now I have remove it and install VS2010.

Once I installed VS2010, I changed the number version of format version to 11.0.0 but it's doesn't work and I get error dialog "one or more project in the solution were not loaded correctly please see the output Window for details".

Comment: Can you please post the content of the output Window ?

Comment: You're not supposed to change the project file - the solution should be fully backward-compatible with VS2010.

Comment: if your application was under framework 4.0 and you are not using feature of VS2012. Then it will run in VS2010

Answer (score 0):

There is free opensource tool written which is in CodePlex.

[Visual Studio Project Converter](http://vsprojectconverter.codeplex.com/)

Try this out it worked fine for me.

If that dosent work then here are some other SO link with other answers to help you out.

[How to downgrade from Visual Studio 2012 project to Visual Studio 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507901/how-to-downgrade-from-visual-studio-2012-project-to-visual-studio-2008)