# How to downgrade a Visual Studio 2013 project to a Visual Studio 2008 project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2013, downgrade

Is there anyway of downgrading a Visual Studio 2013 project to a Visual Studio 2008 project ? I need to run some C# programs created in VS 2013 with VS 2008.

Comment: If you just need to run the programs, not change them, just run the .exe

Comment: @KingCronus I need to modify and add data in the files.

Comment: @MitchWheat How should I modify the .csproj file ? I also think that I need to modify something in the .sln file as well

Comment: Why not just use one of the Visual Studio 2013 Express editions?

Comment: @dav_i Because I need it for a project at my collage, and I can only use their software, and I didn't know that they use VS 2008 because they never told us. And I have about an hour and a half to make everything work !

Comment: Incredible that a college (I'm assuming you didn't mean a piece of art), is using VS2008 still. I'd create a new solution and just add in all existing files.

Comment: @JoeStead Sorry, I meant college, but I am in a hurry and I mistaped. Hope it will work.

Comment: @TothLudovicAndreas I realise this, I'm just being pedantic

Answer (score 2):

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507901/how-to-downgrade-from-visual-studio-2012-project-to-visual-studio-2008). But I really wouldn't recommend this, even if it does work, which to be honest is not guaranteed.

Better to either create a new VS2008 solution and just Add Existing...manually bringing in all the source files, or better yet, just sign up for VS Team Services, grab VSExpress 2013, and you don't have to worry about conversion.

Comment: Do you mean that none of those options work for you, and you really need to downgrade the sln/csproj files? Try http://vsprojectconverter.codeplex.com/, which is linked to from one of the answers on my original link. Hopefully it can help you!

Comment: VS 2013 is different, it is not the same as VS 2012. Some new lines are both added in the .sln and .csproj files.

Comment: ok so after reading through your comments on the question, I really don't see any way except to create a new solution in VS2008 and copy in the existing source files from the VS2013 solution. How many files are we talking about and what type of project?