# Downgrade a Visual Studio 2013 solution to VS2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2013

Is there a way to downgrade a solution that was created in VS2013 so I can open it in VS2008?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to downgrade from Visual Studio 2012 project to Visual Studio 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507901/how-to-downgrade-from-visual-studio-2012-project-to-visual-studio-2008)

Comment: Not totally a duplicate (VS2012 // VS2013) but the answer is quite the same (just need to change number)

Comment: True, not a complete duplicate, but the logic for the answer is basically identical.  There was an answer that looks like it's since been deleted that was quite literally a copy/paste of that question's answer with the numbers (mostly) fixed.

Comment: i tried doing it and i got this error [http://tinypic.com/r/r73w9f/8](http://tinypic.com/r/r73w9f/8)