# Convert/downgrade visual studio 2015 solution file to 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2015

How can I downgrade a Visual Studio 2015 solution file to the 2013 solution file that opens natively in Windows? Or, how can I get the Visual Studio Version selector to open the 2015 solution file after I would have uninstalled 2015 RC?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13508049/2342898)? Just try to change "Format Version" in first line of .sln file (Visual Studio 2012 has 12.00, so I assume 2013 is 13.00)

Comment: In my work I use it quite often because we use different versions of VS. That's why I posted this solution as answer. Yet I don't know if @FSB tried it.

Comment: Sure, no need to explain. I've only asked because your answer refers to VS13-12 and I'm not sure if it would also work for VS15-13.

Comment: I had to edit my project files (I believe c++ is the same as c#). See my answer

Answer (score 0):

For C++ project the procedure is kind of similar:

Edit your `.vcxproj` file and change the `ToolsVersion` to `13.0` and all instances of `<PlatformToolset>v140</PlatformToolset>` to `v120`

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="13.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
...
<PlatformToolset>v120</PlatformToolset>
```

**Edit:** I found that you can change the platform toolset via the properties of the project (perhaps less prone to error)

Right click on your project and go to General -> Platform Toolset, change to Visual Studio 2013 (v120).

Comment: As far as I'm concerned `.vcxproj` file is exclusive for C++ projects (or just C# projects doesn't have one). I didn't check your solution on C++, but it won't work with C#.

Comment: Right...in `C#` projects it's `.csproj`. I guess the OP would have had to specify whether they were working in `c++` or `c#`. Since this is given a generic `visual-studio` tag it might be beneficial to have both versions....

Comment: Of course you're right, my bad. I don't know why I was so fixed on C# projects.

Comment: Well, I did say in my comment on your answer "I believe c++ is the same as c#"...turns out I was wrong