# Opening a Visual Studios 2015 project with 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I was using the trial of Visual Studios 2015 to develop a C# app. Now my trial has expired. I would like to continue developing the app in my licensed version of Visual Studios 2013. However, I can't seem to open the `.sln`. The file opens, but it say "Incompatible". Aside from copy pasting all of the code and re-configuring everything, is there another way I can open it?

Comment: https://thepiratebay.se/, joking I dont think so

Answer (score 2):

You can use this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507901/how-to-downgrade-from-visual-studio-2012-project-to-visual-studio-2008/13508049#13508049).

Just change the version VS2015 set on the solution file to the one used by VS2013. In doubt, just create an empty VS2013 project and check which one is it.

Luckily, VS2015 didn't change anything else and it will just work.