# Is there anyway i could run an already coded project with visual studio 2015 on visual studio 2005

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

So here's my problem, i already have a written code with visual studio c++ 2015. I need to run it on a windows server 2003. So basically i need to run it on visual studio 2005. Is there anyway i can do it? Or should i upgrade the visual studio version?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13508049/5653461

Comment: Windows Server 2003 is End-of-Extended-Life. Don't downgrade Visual Studio, upgrade Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I encontered the same issue. But you can also compile for your windows server by changing some project settings:

Right-click on your project -> Settings. In the configuration settings, navigate to general. Now, you can change "platform toolset" to "Visual Studio 2015 - Windows XP". After compiling, the resulting exe should run on your windows server fine. At least, this worked for me.

Comment: Safe for those very few exceptions. Windows Server 2003 had a some functions, XP had not. I used to have server 2003 at home and xp at work back in the days... and sometimes stuff I wrote used things not available on the xp machines.