# How to build a Visual Studio solution in a lower version of Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I wrote a program using VS 2016 and had to send it to someone who is running VS 2013. Since I was using some syntax available to 2016, they couldn't build/run it. I went through and changed the syntax, but want to ensure I caught everything.

Is there a way for me to build the solution with a 2013 configuration so that I can make sure it builds properly before sending it again?

Comment: Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507901/how-to-downgrade-from-visual-studio-2012-project-to-visual-studio-2008/13508049#13508049) I assume it will be similar for 2016/2013

Comment: What syntax available only in 2016?

Comment: @marc_s and `VS2012`

Comment: There is no VS **2016** version - we have 2010, 2012, 2013, 2015, 2017 .... which one do you really mean??

Comment: @summerGhost most notably, expression bodies, i.e.
public string Something => "someString";

Comment: @BJMyers yep, that's what I was looking for. thank you.