# Visual Studio 2017 project not working in VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2017

I was working on a project in VS 2017(trial) but now i have to work on VS 2012 instead due to company policy. The problem is that now the components in the design are errored out(Error creating control) and i can't proceed any further. Any suggestions on how to make it work in 2012?

Comment: Save it as a 2012 sln.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this solution will be able to help you. Seems like a similar issue although it is for a previous version of Visual Studio.

[How to downgrade from Visual Studio 2012 project to Visual Studio 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507901/how-to-downgrade-from-visual-studio-2012-project-to-visual-studio-2008/13508049#13508049)