# Can i convert vb.net q project file .sln to Visual Studio 6.0

Tags: vb.net

I want to downgrade my project from Visual Studio 2012 to Visual Studio 6.0, is it possible to convert my project?

Comment: No it is not.  You may be able to copy and paste certain sections of code from a VB.NET project to VB6 but even that is doubtful; at least not without some or probably many changes, if the VB.NET code is well-written.

Comment: Just curious. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @Mary because of my medieval prof.

Comment: Take a look at this question's answer, might help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507901/how-to-downgrade-from-visual-studio-2012-project-to-visual-studio-2008/13508049#13508049

Comment: That is so sad. Wasting your time and money on this. After you get your A in this course complain to the administration that you are not getting your money's worth. VB6 came out in 1998. That is an eternity in computer world.